# Conda error: 'Solving environment: failed'

Tags: python, django, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Conda returns `'Solving environment: failed'`. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Here's the full error:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> conda update conda Solving environment: failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please
>   file a support request with your network engineering team.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect
>   to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conda returns 'Solving environment: failed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266535/conda-returns-solving-environment-failed)