# Errors such as: 'Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve' & 'unittest' tab

Tags: tabs, spyder, python-unittest

I am working with spyder - python. I want to test my codes. I have followed the `pip install spyder-unittest` and `pip install pytest`. I have restarted the kernel and restarted my MAC as well. Yet, Unit Testing tab does not appear. Even when I drop down Run cannot find the Run Unit test. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Please report this problem [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-unittest).

Comment: hello Carlos, I actually do not know how to report it on that page. Where to go to report it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda returns 'Solving environment: failed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266535/conda-returns-solving-environment-failed)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So, I solved the issue by running the command:

`conda config --set channel_priority false`.

And then proceeded with the `unittest` download with the command run:

`conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-unittest`.

The first command run `conda config --set channel_priority false` may solve other issues such as:

`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve`

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar problem by doing the following:

```
conda update --all --yes
conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-unittest
```

Comment: `conda update --all --yes` is the key