# Can't install packages with Anaconda 3.4.8

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When running the following command in my terminal:

```
conda install geopandas
```

I get the following results:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

It is the case with geopandas but also any package I'm trying to install.
I've tried:

- Reinstalling Anaconda
- Created a new environment

but nothing works.

Any idea how I could fix that?

Here is the info on the version:conda info

```
  active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/xx/opt/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/xx/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.15.6
       base environment : /Users/xx/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/xx/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/xx/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/xx/opt/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/xx/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Darwin/19.6.0 OSX/10.15.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60338462/843953

Comment: No I already tried that...

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment you're trying to install geopandas in?

Comment: Hi, here is what conda list yields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ conda install -c anaconda pip
$ pip install geopandas
$ pip install Fiona
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a couple of follow up question: I thought you weren't suppose to mix a conda install and a pip install? And what's Fiona?

Comment: If `conda install geopandas` doesn't work you should try `pip install geopandas` and if you use the GDAL libraries you should install Fiona

Answer (score 0):

Here is what `conda list` yields

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py38_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0  
anaconda                  2020.07                  py38_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py38_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py38_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
applaunchservices         0.2.1                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                 py38_1001  
appscript                 1.1.1            py38haf1e3a3_0  
argh                      0.26.2                   py38_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py38_1  
astroid                   2.4.2                    py38_0  
astropy                   4.0.1.post1      py38h01d97ff_1  
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.5.3                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py38_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.9.1                    py38_0  
bitarray                  1.4.0            py38haf1e3a3_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py38_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0  
blosc                     1.19.0               hab81aa3_0  
bokeh                     2.1.1                    py38_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py38_0  
bottleneck                1.3.2            py38hf1fa96c_1  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38haf1e3a3_1000  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
ca-certificates           2020.6.24                     0  
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0  
cffi                      1.14.0           py38hc512035_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cloudpickle               1.5.0                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
conda                     4.8.4                    py38_0  
conda-build               3.18.11                  py38_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py38h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.9.2            py38ha12b0ac_0  
curl                      7.71.1               hb0a8c7a_1  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0  
cython                    0.29.21          py38hb1e8313_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py38h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.20.0                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.20.0                     py_0  
dbus                      1.13.16              h18a8e69_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diff-match-patch          20200713                   py_0  
distributed               2.20.0                   py38_0  
docutils                  0.16                     py38_1  
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001  
expat                     2.2.9                hb1e8313_2  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py38h1de35cc_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flake8                    3.8.3                      py_0  
flask                     1.1.2                      py_0  
freetype                  2.10.2               ha233b18_0  
fsspec                    0.7.4                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             hb0f4f8b_2  
gevent                    20.6.2           py38haf1e3a3_0  
glib                      2.65.0               hc5f4afa_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py38h6ef4df4_3  
greenlet                  0.4.16           py38haf1e3a3_0  
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h3134771_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.1                        py_0  
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3  
idna                      2.10                       py_0  
imageio                   2.9.0                      py_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py38_0  
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_1  
ipykernel                 5.3.2            py38h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython                   7.16.1           py38h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py38_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py38_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.17.1                   py38_0  
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json5                     0.9.5                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py38_1  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7  
jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0  
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py38_0  
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0  
keyring                   21.2.1                   py38_0  
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py38h04f5b5a_0  
krb5                      1.18.2               h75d18d8_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py38h1de35cc_0  
lcms2                     2.11                 h92f6f08_0  
libarchive                3.4.2                haa3ed63_0  
libcurl                   7.71.1               h8a08a2b_1  
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h1de35cc_1  
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.16                 h1de35cc_0  
liblief                   0.10.1               h0a44026_0  
libllvm9                  9.0.1                h21ff451_1  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h0a44026_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha12b0ac_1  
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_1  
libxml2                   2.9.10               h3b9e6c8_1  
libxslt                   1.1.34               h83b36ba_0  
llvm-openmp               10.0.0               h28b9765_0  
llvmlite                  0.33.0           py38ha11be7d_1  
locket                    0.2.0                    py38_1  
lxml                      4.5.2            py38h63b7cb6_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.2                h0a44026_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h1de35cc_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h1de35cc_1  
matplotlib                3.2.2                         0  
matplotlib-base           3.2.2            py38h5670ca0_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py38_1  
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h1de35cc_1001  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py38hc64f4ea_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h959d312_0  
mock                      4.0.2                      py_0  
more-itertools            8.4.0                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.2                h9066e36_1  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py38_0  
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py38h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py38_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py38_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py38_1  
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.4                        py_1  
nltk                      3.5                        py_0  
nose                      1.3.7                 py38_1004  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py38_0  
numba                     0.50.1           py38h959d312_1  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py38hce01a72_0  
numpy                     1.18.5           py38h1da2735_0  
numpy-base                1.18.5           py38h3304bdc_0  
numpydoc                  1.1.0                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                       py_0  
openpyxl                  3.0.4                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h1de35cc_0  
packaging                 20.4                       py_0  
pandas                    1.0.5            py38h959d312_0  
pandoc                    2.10                          0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py38_1  
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
path                      13.1.0                   py38_0  
path.py                   12.4.0                        0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py38_1  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py38_0  
pcre                      8.44                 hb1e8313_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py38_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py38_1  
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py38_1001  
pillow                    7.2.0            py38ha54b6ba_0  
pip                       20.1.1                   py38_1  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py38_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py38_0  
ply                       3.11                     py38_0  
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0  
psutil                    5.7.0            py38h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py38_0  
py                        1.9.0                      py_0  
py-lief                   0.10.1           py38haf313ee_0  
pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h1de35cc_1  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py38ha12b0ac_0  
pydocstyle                5.0.2                      py_0  
pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0  
pylint                    2.5.3                    py38_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py38h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py38h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_1  
pytables                  3.6.1            py38h4727e94_0  
pytest                    5.4.3                    py38_0  
python                    3.8.3                h26836e1_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_1  
python-language-server    0.34.1                   py38_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.9                        py_0  
python.app                2                       py38_10  
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1            py38h1de35cc_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py38haf1e3a3_1  
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py38hb1e8313_1  
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.7.2                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.7.5                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  8.0                  h1de35cc_0  
regex                     2020.6.8         py38haf1e3a3_0  
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0  
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
rope                      0.17.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.9.4                    py38_1  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py38haf1e3a3_1  
scikit-image              0.16.2           py38h6c726b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.23.1           py38h603561c_0  
scipy                     1.5.0            py38hbab996c_0  
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py38_0  
setuptools                49.2.0                   py38_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py38_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py38_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py38h0a44026_0  
six                       1.15.0                     py_0  
snappy                    1.1.8                hb1e8313_0  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.2.1                      py_0  
sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0  
soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_0  
sphinx                    3.1.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py38_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.3                      py_0  
spyder                    4.1.4                    py38_0  
spyder-kernels            1.9.2                    py38_0  
spyder-unittest           0.4.1                      py_0    spyder-ide
sqlalchemy                1.3.18           py38haf1e3a3_0  
sqlite                    3.32.3               hffcf06c_0  
statsmodels               0.11.1           py38haf1e3a3_0  
sympy                     1.6.1                    py38_0  
tbb                       2020.0               h04f5b5a_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py38_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0  
tk                        8.6.10               hb0a8c7a_0  
toml                      0.10.1                     py_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py38h1de35cc_1  
tqdm                      4.47.0                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py38_0  
typing_extensions         3.7.4.2                    py_0  
ujson                     1.35             py38h1de35cc_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py38_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.25.9                     py_0  
watchdog                  0.10.3           py38haf1e3a3_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py38h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.1                    py38_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                      py_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.9                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.19.5                   py38_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py38_0  
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0  
yapf                      0.30.0                     py_0  
zeromq                    4.3.2                hb1e8313_2  
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zope                      1.0                      py38_1  
zope.event                4.4                      py38_0  
zope.interface            4.7.1            py38h1de35cc_0  
zstd                      1.4.5                h41d2c2f_0
```