# Stuck at Solving Environment on Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am running OSX Catalina. After downloading Anaconda, I'm having trouble `downloading external packages`. I tried in both the GUI and the terminal, but the process keeps getting stuck at **"Solving environment"**.

I understand creating a new environment can be a workaround, but I would rather fix the issue at hand.

Any ideas?

Comment: conda config --set channel_priority flexible

Comment: Didn't work for me :/

Comment: Doesn't look like a downloading problem. Solving occurs locally and scales poorly when trying to install everything in a single monolithic environment (such as Anaconda's **base**). I would recommend that you reconsider creating a new environment. Also, since this is a fresh install, consider Miniconda instead of Anaconda.

Comment: The issue is it is getting stuck at solving when trying to download external python packages like  geopandas or pdfminder regardless of how big or small.

Comment: It seems like the issue has to do with conda because I can install packages fine using pip

Comment: What command(s) lead to this issue?

Comment: me too have this issue

Answer (score 64):

The following steps may work to resolve the issue.

```
conda config --remove channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

if it doesn't work then try this

```
conda update conda
```

if nothing works try seeing this [github solution](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9367#issuecomment-558863143), it worked for many.

Comment: Tried both and they didn't work. Do I need to change the file path to a specific path to make these downloads? Currently just at /Users/myname

Comment: I just tried that, and it works but the solution for that is basically just creating a new environment, which I feel is more of a workaround that an actual fix. I don't understand why I am facing this issue as my old macbook worked fine without needing to create a new environment

Comment: try this `conda config --set channel_priority strict`,did it work? or even this

 add these paths to my environment variables:

C:\Anaconda3 

C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin

C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin

C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin

C:\Anaconda3\Scripts

change path according to your directory paths

Comment: I changed the channel priority to strict and to flexible but both still didn't work. I don't understand how to add paths to the environment variables. Also I'm using MacOS

Comment: It seems like the issue has to do with conda because I can install packages fine using pip

Comment: _`conda config --remove channels conda-forge`_ Is OP using conda-forge in the first place?

Comment: `'conda-forge' is not in the 'channels' key of the config file`

Answer (score 53):

running

```
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```

worked for me

Update, still ran into some issues so I found [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba), and oh my god my life changed conda is the worst package manager ever

all my issues were solved when I used mamba

```
# install mamba
conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba

# use mamba
mamba install pandas
```

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed the issue for me, on a brand new Python install.

Comment: I hit this issue trying to install mamba unfortunately :/

Comment: Had to wait over an hour to get Mamba installed (thanks Conda ) - but its speed is life changing!

Comment: I confirm that installing mamba and then running the commands fixed everything _fast_!

Comment: mamba install pointed out the mistake of why the installation took so long (apparently the wrong version of python when creating the environment). After I create a new one with the correct python version, mamba installs it and voila.

Comment: You can use the mamba solver in conda, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71759217/7952998

Comment: Amazing. I'll add my comment to the roster of "this solved my problem and made my programming life easier"

Answer (score 45):

use this:

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

pay attention that it is **channel_priority** and not **priority_channel**

Comment: In case it helps someone: This solved my "Solving Environment take forever" problem, but I also had to re-order the list of channels in my `environment.yml` file. I put `conda-forge` first, then package-specific channels like `pytorch`, then put `defaults` last. From the docs it seems that this causes conda to skip searching in the low-priory channels once a package is found in a high-priority channel, thus shrinking the search-space, but then the channel order matters very much.

Comment: This answer reduced the time needed for 'solving environment' for me, after doing ´conda update conda' outside the problematic environment. @avivr's comment also helped to put the channels in the right order. Using something like this ´pytorch::torchaudio´ instead of adding pytorch to the channels list reduced the env creation time (and some conflicts) for me.

Comment: @avir Thank you so much for your helpful comment. It solved my issue. Though I don't understand why setting it to "strict" and having "conda-forge" first is necessary, as many others suggest to simply set the priority ordering to "flexible". How on earth did you find that solution!? :)

Comment: This alone did nothing for conda version : 22.11.1, conda-build version : 3.22.0, python version : 3.9.13.final.

Answer (score 24):

Many good comments already - let me try to consolidate and add a few more thoughts:

The main background point is that conda is solving a *boolean satisfiability problem* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem (colloquially: *dependency hell* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

More details here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.13.x/dev-guide/deep-dive-solvers.html

In the very early days, with relatively few packages, it was not the end of the world. Now, with many packages each with many versions, conda's non-optimised code can take forever.

1. **mamba** is a kind of conda clone rewritten in C, so much much
   faster. Works like a charm. The recommended way to install it is to
   download mambaforge, otherwise you can install it from anaconda or
   miniconda. Read the docs: https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. If you cannot install mamba, you can use the **mamba solver** with
   conda. details on the Anaconda website: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-is-fast-now
3. **mamba and the libmamba solver do not work behind a corporate proxy with zscaler**. This is a bug with zscaler, which sends back packets with "_ransfer-Encoding" instead of "Transfer-Encoding". This throws off mamba but not conda. the bug is documented on github https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/2197 and https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/2438
4. If you have access to mamba on one computer but not another, you can: **create an environment with mamba** based on a yml file which contains only the packages you need  (e.g. pandas); once the environment is created, you can export the yml file, which will contain all the dependencies you hadn't specified (e.g. numpy and pandas) as well as the exact versions of each package. You can then create a new environment on the computer with conda only, based on the more detailed yml file. This way, the slower conda doesn't have to solve that package x is at version 2.3 but only version 1.9 works with package y etc
5. Solution 4 still requires conda to solve a problem, even if a more limited one. If even that takes forever, you can build the environment with mamba then export a requirements file in the format required by pip, and **install all the packages with pip** in the slower PC. This is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239980/4045275
6. In general, **try to avoid huge environments with loads of packages you do not need**. For the same reason, avoid Anaconda, if you can, and just build the environments you need with miniconda, miniforge or mambaforge. If you have projects of different kind, e.g. a set of datascience projects and one of web-related stuff, maintain two separate environments. Smaller environments with fewer packages means less chance for conflicts and faster solving times for conda.
7. **set *channel priority* to strict**. This means that conda will search channels in the order you specified in your .condarc file, so it won't search the 2nd channel if it found all it needed in the 1st https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html
8. For the reason above, if you know most of your packages are available in two channels, **put the smaller channel first**. This is one of the reasons why, with default settings, miniconda is faster than miniforge: because miniconda searches te conda repository, while miniforge the conda-forge, which is much much larger. But be mindful of the licence terms  https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-commercial-edition-faq whereby commercial users require a licence to access the anaconda repository - but not, if I understand correctly, to access conda-forge

If you know of any other potential solutions or suggestions, do share!

Lastly, I'd add that the newer versions of conda introduced parallel downloading, but, in my experience, the main bottleneck is not the download but solving the environment.

Answer (score 12):

The following works for me.

Spin-off on https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11919

Instead of waiting (maybe hours) to resolve SAT (A well-known NP-Complete problem) environment, it would be helpful for you to install the faster Conda resolver (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community). Just so you know, the resolver is not installed by default with Anaconda, so you need to install it manually.

```
sudo conda update -n base conda

sudo conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver

conda config --set solver libmamba
```

Rerun `conda install`

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 \
 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Of course trying to install mamba gets you stuck on solving environment!

Answer (score 10):

Please, check that python is actually listed in `environment.yml` or `conda create -n your_environment --file requirements.txt python=3.7`.
Otherwise, conda is traversing all versions of python available.
[Check that Python is listed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cikC5.png)

Comment: This, combined with this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68019710/3250829 was what solved my problem.  I put in the Python version in my environment YAML file instead and the env got built almost immediately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

for updated conda version over `4.12.0` 'Libmamba' with advantages like:

- Improve conda’s resolving speeds by 50-80%*
- Maximize backwards compatibility so as to not break any current
  functionality
- Build the plugin infrastructure for others to create custom solvers

are mentioned in [Anaconda's official blog post, A Faster Solver for Conda: Libmamba](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community)

so for making libmamba your default solver(make sure your conda version is 4.12):
`conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver`

and to try it temporarily:`conda create -n demo --experimental-solver=libmamba --dry-run install <some package>`

Answer (score 3):

It might be taking long because of package version conflicts. My solution was to install some packages using **pip** instead of **conda install**.
For example:

`pip install tensorflow`

Try this in a new environment so it doesn't mess up your existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue while creating my conda environment using environment.yml file.

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

My issue was fixed by updating conda and setting channel priority to strict:

```
conda update conda
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

Answer (score 2):

conda config --remove channels conda-forge

conda config --set channel_priority flexible

This fixed the problem with the solving environment step. After that I was able to update packages (such as conda and anaconda) and sort out various dependency issues.

Answer (score 2):

After some reading I found out the `.condarc` file is not created by default (is stated by the official Anaconda [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html). So what I did is delete de `.condarc` file and then used the following command

```
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```

And then it got unstuck

Then I tried `conda update conda` just to test it, and everything worked again.

Comment: On a Jetson AGX Orin / linux-aarch64 board, this worked for me! (all other suggestions resulted in hanging conda) 
I first deactivated all environments, then the steps as described by @el_xino, 
After that: conda activate base and created a brand new environment just to be sure that no old-stuff would be messing up the solution.
conda install -c pytorch -c nvidia -c conda-forge pytorch torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.8 ultralytics
Immediately resolved the right channels and I was able to the packages.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue running macOS Monterey, with conda taking *an age* to solve the environment, failing, and causing immense frustration.

My first suggestion would be to install Mamba [[1](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge)], of which you have two options. If conda **does** work, but just takes a long time, you can try

> conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge

If conda won't install anything at all, you can try uninstalling anaconda3 using `conda install anaconda-clean`, then `anaconda-clean --yes`, then `rm -rf anaconda3`,`rm -rf ~/anaconda3` and `rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3`. From there, download the Mambaforge .sh file [[1](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge)], and run

> bash ~/Downloads/Mambaforge-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

Follow the install, and treat mamba exactly how you would treat conda. Then it's simply a matter of selecting your interpreter in your IDE of choice! You'll find that mamba is *way* faster.

Failing this, you can try using `which pip`, and then `pip install [your package]`. I wouldn't advise this one for lots of packages, as you are essentially bypassing the dependancy check, however for small things, it should work fine. Try it, and uninstall it if you get any clashes. Happy fixing!

Answer (score 2):

set conda-forge highest priority, remove defaults channel

```
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --remove channels defaults
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

make sure most your package from conda-forge, not defaults.
If it doesn't work, try

```
conda update --all
conda clean -a //use with caution
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems trying to install external packages such as graph-tools and I solved it by creating a new environment. I know you prefer other options but it's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very simple but make sure you're in your environment

```
conda activate <Your Environment>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also want to check your ~/.conda directory permissions. I installed conda on my MacOS using Homebrew and for some reason this directory had only read/write permissions for root. After changing the permissions and following the [instructions from above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63734616/51264), everything works smooth and fast now

Answer (score 0):

upgrading conda base package has fixed it.
ref : https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/rpm-debian.html

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i tried to install packages for my env i tried the `conda env update -f environment.yml` even doesn't worked (in yml file i have name: tf2 that i point to update my env still doesnt upgraded)
but now which i tried this it worked :d

```
conda activate tf2
conda env update -n tf2 -f environment.yml --prune
```

Answer (score 0):

For other weary travelers: if you find conda taking hours to solve an environment, try install packages one at a time. Works like a miracle.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that may not have been mentioned is that the dependencies that you may want to install within your conda env are already installed.
Using conda-list within your env you may confirm.

With a package such as tethys platform they did not mentioned this and i was left wondering why my conda install process kept getting stuck at the solving stage. Late into the night bingo checked into my env and sure enough the dependencies where already installed. Now can progress to my next phase.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for tensorflow and solved it by doing the next:

- create new environment  `conda create -n tf tensorflow`
- moved to the new environemnt `conda activate tf`
- downloaded my package there.

it worked and solved the issue, I think this happened due to not completing a previous install and got stuck in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried using the Visual Studio code terminal to create a new environment and install python version 3.6 with the following command,

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.6
```

But it hangs in the solving environment section.

The solution was to go to the anaconda prompt(run as admin),

first, deactivate base env

```
conda deactivate
```

create new env

```
conda create -n env_name
```

activate your new environment

```
conda activate env_name
```

Then do whatever you want in the env(in my case, I installed a specific version of python)

```
conda install python=3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

cannot provide a solution but I have to say that it's not "stuck"

It's just sooooo slow.

```bash
Examining conflict for _anaconda_depends anaconda _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf:  51%|███████████████████████▎                      | 33/65 [14:53:43<14:00:25, 1575.79s/i|
```

Sometimes it looks like to be stuck because the prompt is not changing, but actually it's because the limited width of console is intercepting the prompt. Conda do have a progress bar and an estimated finish time.

---

Well yes, the time is deadly long, as long as several days on my old i5-8300H...but if you leave it alone and keep waiting it'll finally work.

---

20230509 update:
Finally it's over after ~48h of running.
This is a part of what it'll finally print out.

```bash
Package backports.functools_lru_cache conflicts for:
backports.functools_lru_cache
anaconda -> astroid==1.6.5=py27_0 -> backports.functools_lru_cache
conda-build -> conda-verify -> backports.functools_lru_cache
conda-verify -> backports.functools_lru_cache
_anaconda_depends -> backports.functools_lru_cache
prompt-toolkit -> wcwidth -> backports.functools_lru_cache
wcwidth -> backports.functools_lru_cache
spyder -> pylint[version='>=1.0'] -> backports.functools_lru_cache
anaconda -> backports.functools_lru_cache[version='1.4|1.5|1.5|1.6.4',build='py27h9586e20_1|py27_1|py_2|pyhd3eb1b0_0']

Package six conflicts for:
prompt-toolkit -> six[version='>=1.9.0']
conda-verify -> six
anaconda-navigator -> anaconda-client[version='>=1.6.14'] -> six
conda[version='>=4.13.0'] -> conda-package-handling[version='>=1.3.0'] -> six[version='>=1.5.2']
matplotlib-inline -> traitlets -> six
importlib_metadata -> pathlib2 -> six
pip -> html5lib -> six[version='>=1.9']
conda-build -> six
ipython -> prompt-toolkit[version='>3.0.1,<3.1.0'] -> six[version='>=1.9.0']
zipp -> more-itertools -> six[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0']
traitlets -> six
anaconda -> asttokens==2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> six[version='>=1.0.0,<2.0.0|>=1.10|>=1.4.1|>=1.5|>=1.9.0|>=1.6.0|>=1.5.2|>=1.15.0|>=1.13.0|>=1.12.0|>=1.4.0|>=1.9|>=1.11.0|>=1.12,<2|>=1.7.3|>=1.10.0|>=1.4']
pickleshare -> pathlib2 -> six
python-dateutil -> six[version='>=1.5']
ipykernel -> packaging -> six
```

Since it's gonna be reaaaally long, it would almost 100% take all of your console buffer. If you want to analyze the result be sure to redirect it into a file in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, trying to update a package (e.g. `conda update sqlalchemy`) caused conda to hang during the 'solving environment' step, but asking Conda to install it (e.g. `conda install sqlalchemy`) allowed the update to be made. In the latter case, the 'solving environment' step didn't take long at all. I'm not sure why this would be the case, but consider replacing 'update' with 'install' if you're having trouble with update operations.

Answer (score -3):

Choose one:

- Start fresh with a new Anaconda installation. Pay attention during
  installation to make sure that your install path is a subfolder of
  your home folder, such as /Users/me/anaconda3
- Start fresh using the
  .sh installer instead of the .pkg installer. This installer makes it
  simpler to choose the destination path, and gives you more choice on
  how you want your shell to behave.

[check out the link for more details](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update)

[This is another answer for environment failure, but for windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266535/conda-returns-solving-environment-failed)

Answer (score -3):

Try installing ANACONDA3 2019-3.
I had similar issues but after installing the above version of anaconda they were all fixed.

Comment: Even a completely removal and clean installation did not work for me.

Answer (score -3):

This fixed the hang for me.  Although the install went on to fail.
`conda config --set priority_channel strict`