# How to install Librosa on M1 Mac?

Tags: python, macos, conda, librosa, apple-m1

is it possible to install Librosa on M1 Mac? I tried pip and Conda by `conda install -c conda-forge librosa` (miniforge), but getting this error:

```
# conda install -c conda-forge librosa
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

Comment: The last I heard was that numpy, which librosa depends upon, is not readily available for M1, [because of a missing Fortran compiler](https://developers.slashdot.org/story/20/11/14/235253/why-apple-silicon-needs-an-open-source-fortran-compiler)—but that may be old news.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is working (somehow). Using a workaround with miniforge it works like this:

```
brew install miniforge
```

Create and activate new env:

```
conda create -n .venv python
conda activate .venv
```

Now, install scikit-lean and desired librosa:

```
conda install scikit-learn librosa
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70147535)

```
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```

It worked for me!