# ‘’The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully‘’ always appears

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to install new packages from anaconda and this message has appeared:

```
(base) C:\Users\lenovo>conda install anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
```

I tried with `conda install anaconda`,`conda update --all` and `conda install anaconda-clean`,respectively，but it persists.

I CANT EVEN UNINSTALL ANACONDA DUE TO THE SAME ISSUE!
Did anyone get any progress on this?

Here are some details：

```
(base) C:\Users\lenovo>conda install anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py38_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::astropy==5.0.2=py38h6f4d8f0_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::bkcharts==0.2=py38_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::bokeh==2.4.2=py38haa244fe_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::bottleneck==1.3.4=py38h6f4d8f0_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::daal4py==2021.5.0=py38he5193b3_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::dask==2022.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::h5py==2.10.0=py38h5e291fa_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::imagecodecs==2022.2.22=py38h19b08ce_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::imageio==2.16.1=pyhcf75d05_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::matplotlib==3.5.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::matplotlib-base==3.5.1=py38h1f000d6_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_fft==1.1.0=py38h45dec08_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_random==1.1.1=py38h47e9c7a_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::networkx==2.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::numba==0.55.1=py38h5858985_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::numexpr==2.7.1=py38h25d0782_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::pandas==1.4.1=py38h5d928e2_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::patsy==0.5.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::pyerfa==2.0.0.1=py38h6f4d8f0_1
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::pytables==3.6.1=py38ha5be198_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch::python-jsonrpc-server==0.3.4=py_1
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::python-language-server==0.34.1=py38_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::pywavelets==1.3.0=py38h6f4d8f0_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::scikit-image==0.19.2=py38h5d928e2_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::scikit-learn==1.0.2=py38hb60ee80_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::scikit-learn-intelex==2021.5.0=py38haa244fe_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::scipy==1.8.0=py38ha1292f7_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::seaborn==0.11.2=hd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::seaborn-base==0.11.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64::spyder==4.1.4=py38_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::statsmodels==0.13.2=py38h6f4d8f0_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::tifffile==2022.3.16=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pytorch/win-64::torchaudio==0.11.0=py38_cpu
  - pytorch/win-64::torchvision==0.12.0=py38_cpu
  - defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2021.11=py38_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

Conda Info

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : G:\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\lenovo\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\lenovo\.condarc
          conda version : 4.12.0
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.6=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : G:\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : G:\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/win-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/win-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/win-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/noarch
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : G:\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\lenovo\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : G:\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\lenovo\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.8.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.22000
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Did you figure out a fix for this? Seeing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem as you: couldn't install fbprophet and failed to solve the environment when I tried to update conda. As suggested in [this website](https://debugah.com/solving-the-problem-of-solving-environment-failed-of-conda-1814/) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734508/stuck-at-solving-environment-on-anaconda), I tried the command `conda config --set channel_priority flexible`. After that, I could run `conda install anaconda` and the environment failed to solve at the first time, but then downloaded / downgraded / changed the packages successfully.