# pip installing environment.yml as if it's a requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-packaging, requirements.txt

I have an `environment.yml` file, but don't want to use Conda:

```yaml
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - matplotlib=2.2.2
```

Is it possible to have `pip` install the dependencies inside an `environment.yml` file as if it's a `requirements.txt` file?

I tried `pip install -r environment.yml` and it doesn't work with `pip==22.1.2`.

Comment: No, but you can always parse the yaml yourself using Python. I'm not familiar with Conda, but it looks like it might be as simple as extracting the `dependencies` list and then either invoking pip directly using subprocess` or outputting each entry as one line in a `requirements.txt` file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `pip` does not support this format. The format it expects for a requirements file is documented [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/). You'll have to convert the `environment.yml` file to a `requirements.txt` format either manually or via a script that automates this process. However, keep in mind that not all packages on Conda will be available on PyPI.

Answer (score 15):

Based on [Beni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72824693/14473118) implementation, I just wanted to adjust the code since it has lots of errors;

```py
import os
import yaml

with open("environment.yaml") as file_handle:
    environment_data = yaml.safe_load(file_handle)

for dependency in environment_data["dependencies"]:
    if isinstance(dependency, dict):
      for lib in dependency['pip']:
        os.system(f"pip install {lib}")
```

Comment: This answer solves the problem and should be marked as the solution!

Comment: This answer only solves the very limited case where there are `pip: ` dependencies declared the YAML. Any dependencies listed as Conda packages are completely ignored.

Comment: First, maybe because the question is asking about how to install packages within the `.yaml` file using `pip`. I don't think this is limiting installation. In many cases, you can't use Conda or installing it is time expensive – we have Colab, for example, or a remote server where you want to do a specific task.

Comment: It is limited and take the OP YAML as an example: it lacks a `pip:` section, so this code would do nothing given it. On Colab, `condacolab` works fine directly - no need to convert. For other situations, Micromamba is standalone (no install) and fast.

Comment: I have not known that before. I will check this out!

Comment: Here is a pastable oneliner version python -c "import os, yaml; [os.system(f'pip install {lib}') for dependency in yaml.safe_load(open('environment.yaml'))['dependencies'] if isinstance(dependency, dict) for lib in dependency.get('pip', [])]"

Comment: I just wish it would ignore versions

Comment: This batch one liner, lets you test all the lines in environement.yaml to make sure they're installed @echo off & for /f "tokens=2* delims=-" %i in (environment.yaml) do ( for /f "tokens=1 delims=<>=@" %j in ("%i") do ( python -c "import sys; exec('try: import %j; sys.exit(0)\nexcept ImportError: sys.exit(1)')" && echo %j: OK || echo %j: missing ) )

Answer (score 7):

I've implemented what [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian) suggests in his comment.

This converts the `environment.yaml` to `requirements.txt`:

```py
import yaml

with open("environment.yaml") as file_handle:
    environment_data = yaml.load(file_handle)

with open("requirements.txt", "w") as file_handle:
    for dependency in environment_data["dependencies"]:
        package_name, package_version = dependency.split("=")
        file_handle.write("{} == {}".format(package_name, package_version))
```

And this installs the dependencies directly with `pip`:

```py
import os
import yaml

with open("environment.yaml") as file_handle:
    environment_data = yaml.load(file_handle)

for dependency in environment_data["dependencies"]:
    package_name, package_version = dependency.split("=")
    os.system("pip install {}=={}".format(package_name, package_version))
```

NOTE: I've omitted error handling and any other variations of package definitions (e.g., specification of a package version greater than or equal to a certain version) to keep it simple.

Answer (score 5):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72824497/570918) makes important points: there is not direct conversion because Conda is a general package manager and so includes additional packages. Furthermore, Conda packages can often go by different names. None of the proposed parsing solutions cover this situation.

Personally, I think the most efficacious *complete* approach is to recreate the environment with Mamba, then use `pip` in the environment to dump out a legitimate `requirements.txt`.

```bash
# use mamba, not conda
mamba env create -n foo -f environment.yaml
mamba install -yn foo pip
mamba run -n foo pip list --format freeze > requirements.txt
mamba env remove -n foo
```

That is, don't overthink it and use the reliable tools at hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a script I've used the following one-liner to generate the requirements.txt file from an env.yml file:

```
❯ grep -n "pip:" env.yml | cut -d":" -f1 | xargs -I{} expr {} + 1 | xargs -I{} tail -n +{} env.yml | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*- //' | cut -d"=" -f 1 > requirements.txt
```

This just takes all of the dependencies under the `pip` dependency in the yml and removes the pinned version for pip to handle on its own.