# Is there a method to run a Conda environment in Google Colab?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory

I have a YML file for a Conda environment that runs with Python 3.8.15 (`environment.yml`). I am currently trying to load that file into my Google Colab, based on this answer:
[conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031430/conda-environment-in-google-colab-google-colaboratory/62346425#62346425).

```
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe
!chmod +x Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe
!bash ./Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe -b -f -p /usr/local
```

And while the executable file for Anaconda was installed in my Google Drive folder, when I run the code, it turms out that Colab could not execute that file:

```
./Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe: ./Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

Is there any other method that I could use to install Anaconda to work with it in Google Colab? And furthermore, how should I load my `environment.yml` file after getting Anaconda to run in Colab?

Comment: If your purpose is just to replicate the packages in the Conda env, an alternative way is to just directly install it from the `yml` file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73527968/11235205) is the code to install packages via pip using conda `yml`.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu the parsing answers in that question are unreliable. One only parses the "pip:" section of packages (safe, but limited); the other ignores the fact that Conda package names do not necessarily directly map to PyPI packages (prone to error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot run a Jupyter notebook (Colab session) with a *new* Conda environment, but you can use Conda to augment the packages in the existing Python installation. Installation is streamlined with `condacolab`. See [the `condacolab` documentation](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab).

An quick example would go something like:

**First Cell**

```python
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install() # expect a kernel restart
```

**Second Cell**

```python
mamba install [pkg1 pkg2 ...]

# or, if you have a YAML
mamba env update -n base -f env.yaml
```

In the YAML case, you must match the same version of Python with the Colab version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am uploading my YML file, but the problem is, although my Python version in Conda is similar with the Colab version (I have checked with ```python --version``` and the results are both 3.8.15), many packages are not loaded (```nothing provide requested```). Even Python 3.8.15 was noted as not provided, which seems weird for my case.

Comment: @HoangCuongNguyen where did you get the YAML? If it was dumped with `conda env export` it [won't work across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142310/transferring-conda-environments-across-platforms). That is, did it come from another Linux machine?

Comment: I got that one from ```conda env export``` though, and also another problem is that currently my Python file is importing from a folder that I have already loaded, but Colab could not recognize it (so I got ```ModuleNotFoundError```, but that might suit for another question).

Comment: Also, I would like to ask that what is the difference between ```conda env export``` and ```conda env export --from-history```, in terms of the YML file result?

Comment: Yeah, Colab file loading is beyond the scope here. The `--from-history` only includes the specifications a user has made from `conda install` commands and will only have versions and build numbers if the user used them. The regular command includes *everything* in the environment, and specifies the builds, which is what makes it incompatible for cross-platform.

Comment: Realize these are old comments, but revisiting I believe it worth pointing out that only the minor version of Python needs to match in the YAML. I.e., if Colab has `3.8.15` you only need `3.8` specified in the YAML.