# After activating conda virtual env in colab, no changes are being made

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, google-colaboratory, virtualenv, miniconda

I am trying to create a miniconda virtual env in colab, but after activating it there are not changes in python latest version and once I run `! conda info --envs` it is not indicating (with the asterisk) any of my env to be used.

There was a similar error, but it is not updated. So I belief is relevant:
[conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031430/conda-environment-in-google-colab-google-colaboratory)

I have been following the latest tutorial that I´ve found: [https://saturncloud.io/blog/getting-started-with-conda-environments-in-google-colab/#:~:text=Setting%20Up%20a%20Conda%20Environment%20in%20Google%20Colab,5%20Step%205%3A%20Activate%20the%20Conda%20Environment%20](https://saturncloud.io/blog/getting-started-with-conda-environments-in-google-colab/#:%7E:text=Setting%20Up%20a%20Conda%20Environment%20in%20Google%20Colab,5%20Step%205%3A%20Activate%20the%20Conda%20Environment%20)

And here is my code, which is the same except for python's version.

```
#Miniconda instalation
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local
# create  new env and activate
!conda create --name model1_env2 python=3.6 -y
!source activate /usr/local/envs/model1_env2
```

I also think it could be affected because of this warning:
[Python unexpected behavior becasue of the PYTHONPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfDs5.png). However, I have resolve it with the following code  [changing pythons path colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUAG4.png)

Comment: “*after activating…*” - Conda environments cannot be activated beyond a temporary subprocess in a single cell. That is, not in the sense you hope. Some discussion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75229250/570918