# conda kernel not being selected or changesd from default in aws sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, conda, amazon-sagemaker

I've imported a custom conda environment(python 3.7) into my notebook instance in amazon sage maker and did the setup. The kernel is being detected. However, When I try to run the kernel python 3.10 is being utilized. Ive tried changing the kernel and restarting it but it keeps using a different conda env by default.

-!python --version
Python 3.10.8

-%conda activate test
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

[image]

[image]

Edit 1: tried !conda activate path and !source activate path
[image]

Comment: you can use ```!source activate env_name```

Comment: @Hiren Namera-  tried that. It did not work (Image 2)

Comment: Then try ```conda activate (path of conda env)/env-name-here```

Comment: Tried that. added image to the post. That didn't work either

Comment: try this one ```source /home/param/anaconda3/bin/activate env_name``` this is the last i know

Comment: That didn't work either, thanks for trynna help though

Comment: You can't change kernels in a running kernel. Activation only persists in the bash subprocess, which is new each cell. Basically same situation as Colab (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239829/570918). Instead, one must select the kernel for the entire notebook.