# Install Sage (sagemath) from yml file

Tags: installation, yaml, sage

I'm trying to install Sage on Windows for some research.

I tried installing with `sudo apt update; sudo apt install sagemath` in WSL according to the directions here: https://wiki.sagemath.org/SageWindows, but I got a message about unmet dependencies and won't be installed. Specifically,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.10-venv : Depends: python3-pip-whl but it is not going to be installed
 sagemath : Depends: python3-sage (>= 9.5-4) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sage (< 9.5-4.1~) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: sagemath-doc (= 9.5-4) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: sagemath-jupyter (= 9.5-4) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: sagetex but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install`, but got

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

(I am root)

I tried installing a cloned conda environment from my professor, but I got `normal site-packages not writeable - defaulting to user installation` for a large number of dependencies, and couldn't figure out how to resolve that issue.

I tried installing the environment.yml as requirements.txt, as in [pip installing environment.yml as if it's a requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824468/pip-installing-environment-yml-as-if-its-a-requirements-txt), but `dependencies` is not getting recognized as a dictionary.

I tried installing via source code from https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/sagemath/, but ran into issues running the binary files, and what seemed like circular dependencies.

I tried downloading from mirror from the same website, and couldn't figure out how to run the installation. There are package build directions, but no actual files to install.

If you can't tell, I'm struggling with this quite a bit.

Comment: Perhaps try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? You might also find more help at either ask.sagemath.org or the Google group sage-support.