# Constant Installation/Update Errors with Conda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I am following instructions to install PyChrono https://api.projectchrono.org/pychrono_installation.html
Its failing at this step `conda install -c conda-forge mkl=2020`

It gets stuck at Solving Environment and errors out

I tried to fix it using steps here to install Mamba
[Stuck at Solving Environment on Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734508/stuck-at-solving-environment-on-anaconda)

It errors out on `conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba` with the same error

And pretty much on every command I tested in this thread. Including just running
`conda update -n base conda`

I have a great internet connection. How can this software be so popular if it  can't do such a basic thing as update itself? I thought this was supposed to be a reliable programming environment.

Is there a fix for any of this?

I am using Windows 10, do I need to be on Linux?

Thanks,